# How to apply median filter in all images and store in a directory?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, blur, noise-reduction

```
f = 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\images';
d = ls(f);
d(1,:)=[]
d(1,:)=[]
mkdir('New_images')
for i=1:size(d)
   I=imread(fullfile(f,d(i,:)));
   Kmedian = I;
   for i = 1:3
       Kmedian(:,:,i) = medfilt2(Kmedian(:,:,i));
   end
   Kmedian=imresize(Kmedian,[227 227]);
   imshow(Kmedian)
   imwrite(Kmedian,fullfile('New_images',strcat(num2str(i),'.jpeg')));
end
```

How to use median filter at once.

**Errors:**
In resize (line 5)
Index in position 3 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Error in resize (line 10)
Kmedian(:,:,i) = medfilt2(Kmedian(:,:,i));

Comment: Just call whichever filter method suites you best before showing it? https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/noise-removal.html (e.g. `I = medfilt2(I);`)

Comment: But I am facing error. Can you please add those lines on the code written above sir? i am new in matlab.

Comment: I think it would be best to show what you tried, and what issues you encountered.

Comment: I added "Kmedian = medfilt2(f)"

Comment: and facing these errors

Comment: Error using medfilt2
Expected input number 1, A, to be one of these types:

uint8, uint16, uint32, int8, int16, int32, single, double, logical

Error in medfilt2>parse_inputs (line 107)
validateattributes(a, ...

Error in medfilt2 (line 49)
[a, mn, padopt] = parse_inputs(args{:});

Error in resize (line 3)
Kmedian = medfilt2(f);

Comment: `f` is not an image, it's a string. You need to feed an image to `medfilt2`, for example `I`.

Comment: I am still getting error after feeding images :(

Comment: Please update your question with your latest attempt to apply the filter to `I` so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Remember you should always specify what the error message you encounter is after showing what you tried.

Comment: i also updated the errors now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `medfilt2` function only works on 1 channel at the time. If you have a color image, you will have a 3rd dimension to your pixel "matrix" for red, green, blue channels respectively.

You can still use the `medfilt2` function by either converting your image to grayscale, or apply it to each channel individually.

```matlab
Kmedian = I;
for i = 1:size(Kmedian,3)  % Iterate over all the channels in the image
    Kmedian(:,:,i) = medfilt2(Kmedian(:,:,i));
end
```

*Updated to account for both single and multi channel images*

Comment: Thank you sir. I am still facing 2 errors now. The code and errors are updated above.

Comment: For reference: The question did `Kmedian = medfilt2(I)` when i answered just in case this answer no longer makes sense given the question.

I can only guess you have color and grayscale images mixed (you have not specified) so I edited the answer to account for either.